# how to get data in variable from url. javascript/phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, phonegap-desktop-app

```
$("#listview").append('<li><a class="item" href="new.html?gname='+ groupName + '&gid='+groupId+'"><img src="../icon.png" /><h4>'+ groupName + ' </h4><p>'+ createdON +'</p></a></li>');
```

here is data i am passing to next page. How can i get gname and gid variables with passed data on next page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advice you to use [sessionStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

In your case, In second page (new.html) use the following

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#second",function () {
        var parameters = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];
        parameter = parameters.replace("paremeter=","");  
        alert(parameter);
});
```

for more detailed explanation 
have a look at

http://www.gajotres.net/passing-data-between-jquery-mobile-pages/

if you want to go with sessionStorage and localStorage
the syntax is pretty simple.

in first page set the items

```
localStorage.setItem("gName", "GroupName");
localStorage.setItem("gid", "GroupId");
```

and then in second page get the items

```
var gname=localStorage.getItem("gName"); 
var gid=localStorage.getItem("gid");
```

localStorage is avalible until user clears the cache.if you want it to be temporary use sessionStorage it will cleared as the app is closed.

Comment: in case i use local/session storage. How i would update every time when user clicks on different item from list?

Comment: I've updates the answer. add that statements into onClick event of that list item.